# While Deploying to Google app engine I am getting error

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, sockets

I am using Java to write the code and when deploying the application on google app engine
I am getting this error

```
 An internal error occurred during: "Deploying CToJavaToCloud to Google".
can't parse argument number: 
this.lastRenderedCustomContentContainers = new Array(); 
this.defaultContainer = 'portal_main_view'; this.ignoreHashChange = false;       
this.wait = null;    this.requestParams = null; 
// Hash to view mapping
```

I have used ArrayList to store the data and using the objects of ArrayList to store the data in the DataStore.
Guys help me out with error.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to get your own code to run on Google AppEngine, ensure all the fundamental pieces are in place by building and running an existing debugged project such as Google's [guestbook tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating).  The Data store cannot natively handle an ArrayList or any other kind of Collection, only simpler scalar structures defined in [Properties and value types](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types).

You're evidently new on GAE, your questions show a need to better understand what your compiled Java code is and is not allowed to do on a GAE server.  For example Sockets are restricted (see [Socket Java API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/) and the big picture in [Java Runtime Environment](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) documentation).  You will probably be forced to use the [URL Fetch Java API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) instead of Sockets for your CToJavaToCloud project.